# Image upload on ftp crashes the application if the camera has more aspect ratio in android

Tags: android, ftp, aspect-ratio

I have a camera activity where in i am capturing an image and storing it in a folder and finally uploading it on the ftp.This application works fine when i test it on the samsung,micromax and sony devices..But when installed in Karbonn Titanium S5, the captured image does not get uploaded to the ftp.. The reason that i found out was Aspect Ratio...If the camera aspect ratio is kept as 16:9 the captured image does not get uploaded and crashes and if it is 4:3 it gets uploaded to the ftp..

How can i control the aspect ratio for some devices through my code so that the application does not crash???

Can anybody please help me with this?? I have no idea how i am supposed to do this!!

Please HELP!!

Comment: Could you please provide a LogCat!?

Comment: @A.S. m not able to view the the logcat as the device is not getting detected in eclipse

Comment: So please fix this error before you start developing.

Comment: do `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` you might be able to see the device in DDMS view.